# Div not occupying entire space

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have this piece of code in which the  div men are not occupying the  entire height available.It may be a basic doubt but as I am a newbie plz help me
JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7U3aX/

```
        <div data-role="navbar">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#men" data-ajax="false">Men</a></li>
                <li><a href="#women" data-ajax="false">Women</a></li>
                <li><a href="#kids" data-ajax="false">Kids</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="men" style=" width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute"  >


            <div id="men_Promotion" style=" height:34%; background-color: green" >

            </div>
            <div id="men_Category" style=" height:33%; background-color: black" >

            </div>
            <div id="men_BrandPromo" style=" height:33%; background-color: blue"  >

            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Please make Jsfiddle.

Comment: remove position absolute in your inline style and try may be it works

Comment: Removing that  makes  the   corresponding inner div  invisible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take A look at **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/E63p7/2/)**

You need to add One More Css rule In your style.

```
 .ui-tabs{
            position:static;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following styles to the navbar div will do the job:

```
<div data-role="navbar" style=" z-index: 1; position: absolute; ">
```

fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/7tGTw/

Comment: Thanks for your try , but it didn't work.You can see that in the  demo itself

Comment: Sorry, I thought I updated the fiddle with my changes. here's the updated http://jsfiddle.net/7tGTw/1/